# How can I move the Yoast Schema.org markup to the bottom of the head?

Tags: php, html, schema.org, yoast

I'm trying to figure out how to move the Schema.org markup that Yoast outputs to the bottom of the head.

The only filter I've been able to find only removes the :

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_json_ld_output', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: I don't have specific guidance, but your best bet is probably changing their hook's priority to something higher

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for the tip. Are you suggesting I used something like this: add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpseo_json_ld_output', 999);

Comment: No, I think you need to find the level that Yoast is hooking at and change theirs